# How can I build an arbitary curried function in an F# type provider?

Tags: f#, currying, type-providers

In trying to get type providers to generate more idiomatic code, I've started looking into returning curried functions from the provider.

This little snippet of code:

```
let lambdaTest () =
    let inner =
        <@ fun myInt ->
                fun int2 -> sprintf "A string! %d %d" myInt int2 @>
    let innerType = inner.GetType()
    ProvidedProperty(
        "lambda", 
        innerType.GenericTypeArguments.[0], 
        IsStatic = true, 
        GetterCode = fun _ -> inner.Raw)
```

Seems to work for providing an `int -> int -> string` if I know the desired signature in advance; but ideally I'd like to build the nested lambda functions up dynamically, something like this:

```
let rec inline curry<'a> format (func: Quotations.Expr<'a>) : Quotations.Expr<'a> =
    match format with
    | FString f ->
        curry<string -> 'a> f <@ fun (s : str) -> %func @>
    | FInt f ->
        curry<int -> 'a> f <@ fun (i: int) -> %func @>
    | Other (_, f) ->
        curry<'a> f func
    | End ->
        func
```

Unfortunately, the above isn't valid F# code due to the conflicting return types of the quotations.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that building curried functions with dynamic type (depending on some input) is probably a case where you have to resort to building the quotation by hand using the various `Expr` constructors.

I guess this might be a question related to your [printf type provider](https://twitter.com/mavnn/status/459815484717015040), so I used that as an inspiration. The following function takes a list of format specifiers `args` which can contain either `"s"` for strings or `"n"` for integers. Given e.g. `['s'; 'n']`, it builds a function `string -> (int -> string)` that formats the first two arguments and returns a concatenated string with the results:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let rec buildFunc args printers = 
  match args with
  | 's'::args ->
      // Build a function `string -> (...)` where the `(...)` part is function
      // or value generated recursively based on the remaining `args`.
      let v = Var("v", typeof<string>)
      let printer = <@@ "Str: " + (%%(Expr.Var v)) + "\n" @@>
      // As we go, we accumulate a list of "printers" which are expressions of
      // type `string` that return the variables we are building, formatted...
      Expr.Lambda(v, buildFunc args (printer::printers))
  | 'n'::args ->
      // Pretty much the same, but we use `string<int>` to convert int to string
      let v = Var("v", typeof<int>)
      let printer = <@@ "Num: " + (string<int> (%%(Expr.Var v))) + "\n" @@>
      Expr.Lambda(v, buildFunc args (printer::printers))
  | [] ->      
      // Builds: String.Format [| f1; f2; f3 |] where 'f_i' are the formatters
      let arr = Expr.NewArray(typeof<string>, List.rev printers)
      let conc = typeof<string>.GetMethod("Concat", [|typeof<string[]>|])
      Expr.Call(conc, [arr])
```

I have not tried this in the type provider context, but it can be compiled and evaluated:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter

// Generate 'int -> (string -> (int -> string))'
let fe = buildFunc (List.ofSeq "nsn") []
fe.Type.FullName // Shows the right type in a bit ugly way

// Evaluate the expression & cast to a function type
let f = (EvaluateQuotation(fe) :?> (int -> (string -> (int -> string)))) 
f 1 "a" 2 // Works!
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomas, this is indeed inspired by the printf toy provider - but was also a more general question as it's currently very hard to create an idiomatically F# api via a type provider. I'll try and give your code a try soon (or maybe give it to people as an extension problem at the meetup tomorrow!)

Comment: People can check out this code being used in context now at: http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/type-safe-printf-via-type-providers/ . Thanks again, Tomas!